# jQuery Tooltipster should show a hidden DIV on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltipster

My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../_js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#HHH').tooltipster({
            content: $('#BTE' )
        })
    })
</script>
```

My div is `<div id="BTE">ABCDEFG</div>` and `<div id="HHH"></DIV>`

I want to hide my "BTE" initially and when hover AROUND "hhh", the "bte" should appear. I wonder how to achieve that? I had tried `display:none` but it doesn't work.

Comment: add your code in jsfiddle

Comment: You tried display:none using css or jquery

Comment: Yes, I tried display none, but either I got neither appear or both appear

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use any plugins, try like this,

```
// Initially hide the tooltip <div>
$("#HHH").hide();

// On mouse-over add some CSS and show the tooltip <div>
$("#BTE").mousemove(function (e) {
    $("#HHH").css("top", e.pageY);
    $("#HHH").css("margin-left", e.pageX);
    $("#HHH").show();
});

// On mouse-out hide the tooltip <div> again
$("#BTE").mouseout(function () {
    $("#HHH").hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/37/)

Answer (score 0):

> Try like this: I analysed the plugin and put the solution for your
>   issue. thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#HHH').tooltipster({
        content: $('<div id="BTE">ABCDEFG</div>')
    });
});


<div id="HHH"> 
    This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!
</div>
```

Comment: that works well too! The only thing is that my "ABCDEFG" is a list of <li>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I added 
        $('#HHH').tooltipster({
              content: $('#BTE' ).show()
          }), 
and add another 
   div display none to my "BTE" and it works

as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
   $(function () {
      $('#HHH').tooltipster({
          content: $('#BTE').show()
      })

  }) 
  </script>

  <div style="display:none">
  <div id="BTE" style="display:none">Driven by: <ul><li>Economics of scale (cost advantage)</li>
           <li>Patents and proprietary products</li>
          <li>Brand strength</li>
          <li>Government regulation</li>
          <li>Capital investment requirements</li>
          <li>Access to distribution channels</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you don't add Intially BTE id. Make it in tooltip

Answer (score 0):

This will update the tooltip with the content of the next hidden element (in my case a div with some html inside):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        contentAsHTML: true,
        updateAnimation: false,
        functionBefore: function (origin, continueTooltip) {
            continueTooltip();

            if (!origin.data('cached')) {
                var content = origin.next().contents(); // get the next div
                origin.tooltipster('content', content).data('cached', true);
                origin.tooltipster('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```